# I remove button from layount and it is still there

Tags: android, button, layout

I remove button from layout and when i run app in debug mode i still see this button and it work. Button links to googlemarket.
I remove button from layouts (large, small etc.) xml file and comment /* in class method and controls. I made Invalidate Caches few times.
I work in intellij.
What should i do to see new effect?

Comment: Are you rebuilding it and running it from your IDE or running it from your device? You obviously aren't saving or running the latest build

Comment: As long you add the Button via code you should successfully remove it via code. In XML you perhaps only can make it ivisible and disabled.

Comment: What do you mean "remove button from layout"? Are you trying to remove it permanently from the XML file? Or are you trying to remove/hide it programmatically using Java code?

Comment: I trying to remove it permanently from xml and class. I running it on 2 devices phone and tablet. I remove from devices this application before install new one. I agree with codeMagic it's always start old version but i don't know why and how to fix it?

Comment: What will happened if i remove /.idea folder from app folder and import project again? Is there a chance that i get what i want?

Comment: OK I fixed my problem. I import project again to the same folder (override all files), and remove every problems with modules and libraries. Now everything looks OK.